# How to find data sheet to LED Display?

Tags: led

I'm having trouble understanding what the serial number or type of these LED's are so I can look up the datasheet. The packager didn't label them at all. I've searched and searched and I don't know if I'm getting the right specified datasheet that coordinates with each item. I've listed my invoice and then following that I listed some numbers that are printed real small on all the 1"Tall LED's. Could you guys explain to me how to read these things. I'm confused on what I'm looking at and I need to match them up somehow so I know which one is which.

MY INVOICE:

(1)    COM-09481    7-SegmentDisplay    4-Digit(Blue)

(2)    COM-09482    7-SegmentDisplay    4-Digit(KellyGreen)

(1)    COM-11407    7-SegmentDisplay    1"Tall(Green)            "This is a 4-Digit also"

(2)    COM-11408    7-SegmentDisplay    1"Tall(Blue)             "This is a 4-Digit also"

(1)    COM-11409    7-SegmentDisplay    1"Tall(White)            "This is a 4-Digit also"

(1)    COM-11442    7-SegmentSerialDisplay    (Blue)             "This is a 4-Digit also"

There is a number printed on the side of all the 1" Tall LED's. These numbers are listed below.

ATA804.1AW

ATA804.1AG

ATA804.1AB

ATA804.1AB

Also the other 4 LED's (NOT the 1" LED's) are mixed up also because the packager didn't label which one is which. However the only one that is easy to separate out is the Serial Display so I'm good on that one. But the other three has this printed on the side of them.

YS

YS

YS

Thanks for any help you guys have. I'm just confused on how to read these things and what the numbers mean. I have no idea what COM means or what ATA8041 means which appears on all the 1" LED's or what AW, AG and AB mean. I'm guessing the last letter indicates the color. But still, I need some help in how to read and understand these things correctly and how to type them in when I'm searching for the Datasheet.

I believe these two are the same as AB would most likely mean BLUE.

[image]

[image]

Comment: COM (probably for component) just sounds like the supplier's own stock code. You'll probably need to contact them and ask for either datasheets or the manufacturer and manufacturer part number.

Comment: posting a picture will help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are fairly common and really low-cost 7-segment displays from China, designated thus:

- ATA is the manufacturer code
- ATA8041 is a part number for digit height 0.8 inches, 4-digit display, [datasheet is here](http://dlnmh9ip6v2uc.cloudfront.net/datasheets/Components/LED/1LEDBLUCC.pdf). Never seen an English datasheet for it.
- The trailing 2 letters indicate common anode / cathode, and color. So **AB** = **Common Anode**, **Blue**.

I've seen them on eBay for as little as $1-$1.5 with free international shipping.

---

As a general rule with any unknown 7-segment display, it is easy to determine the pin arrangements using a current-limited supply: I use a **9 Volt battery with a 680 Ohm resistor in series**, for approximately 10 mA available across a pair of probes.

Simply attach the negative probe of such a homegrown tester to one pin at a time, then run the positive probe along each of the other pins, watch for segments lighting up. Repeat the exercise with the positive probe fixed to one pin at a time, and the negative probe for exploring. You'll find out the pin-outs, as well as common anode / common cathode.

The color identification, which seems to be one of the key concerns of the question, is even more obvious - when any segment lights up by the method above, the color is immediately evident!

Comment: Good immediate relief! I hope that the OP corrects the root cause of this issue so that others may also be benefited.

Answer (score 2):

Ignoring non-constructiveness of the question, I would like to answer it as community is becoming lenient. This conclusion is just by looking at other answers.

It seems that this invoice is from Sparkfun.

Easiest way to figure out what is what is to call /contact them. You should also leave them a feedback so that novices like yourself don't have to face such issue.

I usually buy from Mouser and Digikey and each part is package labeled.

Example below:
[image]

Comment: <joke>It looks like they sent you MMCX to SMA cables labelled as 22uF caps! That's why I buy all my components from e-bay!!</joke>

Comment: just took a picture of label from google images. I did not had one handy :-)

Answer (score 0):

I googled the first (sparkfun) product code you mention, COM-09481. The first hit is the sparkfun product page at https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9481 That page has a section Documents, the first link is called *datasheet*. It links to http://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/LED/7-Segment/YSD-439AB4B-35.pdf , which is the (sparkfun copy of) your datasheet. How easy can they make it for you?